# Как преобразовать pd.series символьные строки в np.array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Есть dataset, признак pixel, у него внутри описание пикселей в символьном виде:

```
'100 54 123 423 43'
```

Как преобразовать его в `numpy.array`?

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([['100 50 77 80'],['40 50 69 77']],columns=['pixels'])
#на выходе хочу преобразовать каждый объект pixels в np.array(2,2)
#прошу прощения не умею работать со stackoverflow
```

Пробовал циклом пройтись по всем элементам, сделать сплит, а из это собрать уже `np.array`, но данных слишком много.

Comment: Я вижу вы не ищете простых решений - то вам надо создать матрицу 2x2 из 8 чисел, то с 4x4 (16 элементов) из 8 чисел ;-)

Comment: я просто плохо сформулировал)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [45]: a = df.pixels.str.split(expand=True).astype(int).values

In [46]: a
Out[46]:
array([[100,  50,  77,  80],
       [ 40,  50,  69,  77]])

In [47]: a.dtype
Out[47]: dtype('int32')
```

PS чтобы получить `np.array размером 2,2` из 8 чисел вы должны объяснить по какому принципу вы их хотите получить... ;)

---

**UPDATE:**

> на выходе хочу преобразовать каждый объект pixels в np.array(2,2)

судя по описанию вам нужна 3D матрица размерности: `(<# of rows in DF>, 2, 2)`

```
In [7]: a = a.reshape(-1, 2, 2)

In [8]: a
Out[8]:
array([[[100,  50],
        [ 77,  80]],

       [[ 40,  50],
        [ 69,  77]]])

In [9]: a.shape
Out[9]: (2, 2, 2)
```

Comment: #на выходе хочу преобразовать каждый объект pixels в np.array(2,2)

Comment: @SharkShark, боюсь врядли вам смогут помочь пока вы не покажете в вопросе что вы хотите получить на выходе в виде матрицы / DataFrame / etc. [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @SharkShark, вы хотите получить 3D матрицу размерности `(2,2,2)` ?

Comment: а как потом заменить то что было в датафрейме на то что получилось

Comment: @SharkShark, DataFrame предназначен для хранения скалярных значений в ячейках. Если в ячейках DataFrame хранить более сложные объекты то вы лишаетесь практически всех преимуществ Pandas.